# How to import excel data to dataset without precise values from a column using c# with openXML?

Tags: c#, openxml

My excel having the data as

B

0.23

0.356

The column B having precise decimal like 0.234567 and 0.35689 but i don't want that data.I want the data what i seen.

From below code i'm getting the output as

B

0.234567

0.35689

Please help me to get the data without precise values.

Below is the code i'm using to import the data from excel

```
      public DataSet GetMigrationExcelData(string fileName, string folderPath)
        {
            DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(folderPath + fileName, false))
                {
                    foreach (Sheet sh in doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets)
                    {
                        DataTable dtRecords = new DataTable();
                       
                      
                        Worksheet worksheet = (doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sh.Id.Value) as WorksheetPart).Worksheet;

                       
                        IEnumerable<Row> rows = worksheet.Descendants<Row>();

                        foreach (Row row in rows)
                        {
                          
                            IEnumerable<Cell> cells = GetRowCells(row);


                            if (row.RowIndex.Value == 1)
                            {
                                foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                                {
                                    string columnName = GetValue(doc, cell).Trim();
                                    dtRecords.Columns.Add(columnName);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int i = 0;
                                dtRecords.Rows.Add();
                                foreach (Cell cell in cells)
                                {
                                
                                    if (i < dtRecords.Columns.Count)
                                        dtRecords.Rows[dtRecords.Rows.Count - 1][i] = Convert.ToString(GetValue(doc, cell));                                  
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        dtRecords.TableName = sh.Name;
                        dsData.Tables.Add(dtRecords);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
             return dsData;
        }

public static string GetValue(SpreadsheetDocument doc, Cell cell)
        {
            string value = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                value = cell.CellValue.Text;

                if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                {

                    return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.GetItem(int.Parse(value)).InnerText.ToString();

                }
            }
            catch { }
            return value;
        }

 public static IEnumerable<Cell> GetRowCells(Row row)
        {
            int currentCount = 0;

            foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell in
                row.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell>())
            {
                string columnName = GetColumnName(cell.CellReference);

                int currentColumnIndex = ConvertColumnNameToNumber(columnName);

                for (; currentCount < currentColumnIndex; currentCount++)
                {
                    yield return new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                }

                yield return cell;
                currentCount++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you round/truncate the value in your code?

Comment: I have done that work. But My client  wants exact data what they seen in excel without precise decimals. Please help me to get the data without precise and without roundoff the values.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by precise value? do you want the values to be rounded off or do you just want the integer value?
For example: 0.234567
integer value is: 0
rounded off up to 0 digit after decimal: 0.0
rounded off up to 2 digits after decimal: 0.23
rounded off value up 3 digits after decimal: 0.236

Comment: in excel ,column having the value 0.234567 but user precise it to 0.23 that means he doesn't remove the 4567 . excel precise property is there to hide the decimal values .      Now, my problem is, i want 0.23 only not 0.234567 and 0.356 not 0.35689. if we round off to two decimal we can get the 0.23 if we round off up to 3 decimals we get 0.356.   But we don't know how many decimals he precised. User want only the data what he can see in excel it may be 2 decimal or 3 decimal.